# Why does Eloquent (in Laravel) cast my varchar uuid primary key to an integer resulting in errors?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, uuid, type-conversion

Following up on my last night's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855277/why-does-laravel-eloquents-fresh-function-return-an-object-but-calling-its), I had a good night of sleep and "discovered" that this happens due to automatic casting / type conversion or whatever.

To summerize:

- Models use `uuid`as primary key
- They get them by a `trigger` on insert from mySQL
- To get the uuid generated by the database runtime I call `$model_object->fresh();` [`fresh()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fresh)
- This works when getting the object as a whole, but not when selecting just an attribute

**Model**

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model {

    protected $table = 'Addresses';
    protected $fillable = ['uuid', 'zipCode', 'houseNumber'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';
    //public $incrementing = false;
}
```

**Controller** (where it screws up)

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();
    $address = Address::create($input);
    var_dump($address); exit;
```

[//result (as expected)](http://pastebin.com/2aeTEPPa)

```
    $address = $address->fresh();
    var_dump($address); exit;
```

[//result (as expected)](http://pastebin.com/P3EFP2V3)

```
var_dump($address->uuid); exit;//result (wow): int(0)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the field has a value in in the database? It's empty in your first dump.

Comment: @aynber Yes I'm sure, please reference the `var_dump()` 1 line above the uuid one. If the uuid does not start with a 0 it returns that integer (e.g. 2), so it always returns the first `int` it encounters in the `uuid`

Comment: Maybe [this is the answer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L63)? I think you could override it.

Comment: @alariva Very good call, but after calling `fresh()` it now returns `null` instead of the expected object, just like when setting`public $incrementing` to `false`. I think this is a bug on in the `fresh()` function.

Comment: For now I fixed it by letting PHP generate the `uuid`, but this is just a workaround. code to append: `$uuid = file_get_contents('/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid');
        $input['uuid'] = $uuid;`

Comment: *I'm not sure*, but maybe you could ask on Laravel's forum/chat if there's a way to use UUIDs within your models, maybe this would be a feature request.

Comment: @alariva uuid's itself are not a problem, only if they are generated by the database itself with a trigger. But thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Yeah, I meant of *handling* uuids for model keys to avoid that type conversion issue. However, from this point and on I think its needed some more research :)

Comment: also make sure in the migration uuid('id') not string('id')

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order for this to work I had to manually override the casting type of the primary key in my model.

```
protected $casts = [
  'id' => 'string'
];
```

Answer (score 17):

For those coming here later. You can override the `$keyType` variable in your model with the string type:

```
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

Answer (score 8):

I looked into the `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class and found that the most effective way is to set `$incrementing = false` in your Model.

In my tests both creating and retrieving the model worked as intended.

This is the snipped with the PHP docs comments.

```php
    /**
     * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;
```